# %Rowtype equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm about to convert a stored procedure from pl/sql to SQL Server. The procedure uses a cursor to loop through the results of a `select` query. Is there a SQL Server equivalent to the ORACLE `rowtype` construct?

Comment: If you can throw some more information here we might be able to help you avoid a cursor all together, I just tend to steer away from the old 'don't do it that way' type of answer :)

Answer (score 31):

This is a massive reason to dislike SQL Server when compared to oracle.

I am so disappointed that SS doesn't have %TYPE and %ROWTYPE.  These save hours of work when initially writing code and in the event that the type of a column needs to change, it saves having to go back and re-work all the code.

In Oracle I used to write something like:

DECLARE @MyRowVar AS  ATable%ROWTYPE;

In SQL Server, I just had to write this this:

```
DECLARE @External_ID                AS BIGINT = NULL;
DECLARE @PlatformID                 AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfReseller          AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfClient            AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfExtension         AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallType                   AS NCHAR (10) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallInitiatedDate          AS DATE = NULL;
DECLARE @CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI    AS TIME (0) = NULL;
DECLARE @TimePeriodID               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallAnswered               AS DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @CallAnsweredYN             AS BIT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallDispositionID          AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CountryID                  AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallPrefixID               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @FromNumber                 AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @ToNumber                   AS VARCHAR (80) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallDuration               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToExtension        AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToClient           AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToReseller         AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToAdmin            AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @Flow                       AS VARCHAR (3) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallStart                  AS DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @MoneyUnit                  AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @Prefix                     AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @External_CallID            AS VARCHAR (255) = NULL;
```

This is making me very sad.

Harvey

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 1000 times. I miss PL/SQL. SQL Server doesn't have FOR loop.

Comment: Yup... an upvote of one will have to do... but know I upvoted this many more times in my head.

Comment: TL;DR: SQL Server has no %ROWTYPE or %TYPE, you will have to create variables defining each type.

Answer (score 8):

The SQL way of using a cursor is shown below

```
DECLARE @colA varchar(50), @colB varchar(50)

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
Select columnA, columnB From table

OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @colA, @colB

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--do something with @colA and @colB

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @colA, @colB

END

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

[reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: And it is slow. Avoid cursors as much as you can - which means rewrite the sp ;)

Comment: Speed is not a concern. The procedure will be executed nightly when the systems is offline.

Comment: I would like to avoid declaring so many variables, because the table has more than 40 fields...

Answer (score 5):

As `@HarveyFrench` responded there is no `@rowtype`. To generate all columns variables You can use this select and copy paste from results:

```
SELECT 'DECLARE @customPrefix' + COLUMN_NAME  + '  ' +  DATA_TYPE + ';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'Your_table'
```

Comment: I wish I had access to those tables :(

Answer (score 0):

you can create pass JSON String as the parameter to the SP .. this behaves similar to ROWTYPE

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPInsertPerson]

(

```
@JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

)

AS

BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] (
    [Name], 
    [DOB])
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(@JsonData, '$.personname') AS Name,
    TRY_CAST(JSON_VALUE(@JsonData, '$.dob') AS DATE) AS DOB;
```

END